# Is it a good idea to use airflow to run a long process that contains many SQL Server stored procedures and Python scripts?

Tags: python, sql-server, automation, airflow

I am completely new to Airflow, and trying to figure it out if it is the right tool for my process.

I have a long workflow that runs many SQL Server stored procedures and many more Python scripts that one after the other crunch a lot of data and generates a report.

Is it Airflow the right tool? Could you recommend any tutorial/book/documentation that would help me to achieve my task?

If Airflow is not the answer, what do you recommend?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My approach is to use Airflow, to copy the source tables from sql server to some analytical database ( Big Query / Snowflake ) and process the workload against analytical database in data pipeline in many steps

Comment: Hi Ladislav, thanks for your response. I have a follow up question: the reason for your approach is because is not possible to use SQL server with Airflow?

Comment: No, it is possible use SQL server with Airflow. It depends, when your SQL Server primary use is  to process analytical queries, then in this case you should stay with it. In case your SQL server is more like transactional database, you should do data extraction ETL  to database that is more suitable for generating reports...